# Java: What scenarios call for the use of reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

So from reading some of the articles, the message i got out of it was being able to modify fields and set values to classes in real time without recompiling.

so is it possible to do this to 3rd party java library created classes which no source code is available / is it possible to use reflection to modify class instances on run time?

in what other scenarios is reflection commonly used?

I am trying to understand how reflection can be applicable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any time you're dealing with a string at runtime and want to treat part of that string as an identifier in the language.

1. Remote procedure calling -- treat part of a message received over the network as a method name.
2. Serialization and deserialization -- convert field names to string so you can write the object's fields to a stream and later convert it back into an object.
3. Object-relational mappings -- maintain a relationship between fields in an object and columns in a database.
4. Interfaces with dynamically typed scripting languages -- turn a string value produced by a scripting language into a reference to a field or method on an object.

It can also be used to allow language features to be emulated in the language.
Consider the command line `java com.example.MyClass` which turns a string into a class name.  This doesn't require reflection, because the `java` executable can turn a `.class` file into code, but without reflection it would not be able to write `java com.example.Wrapper com.example.MyClass` where `Wrapper` delegates to its argument as in:

```
class Wrapper {
  public static void main(String... argv) throws Exception {
    // Do some initialization or other work.
    Class<?> delegate = Class.forName(argv[0]);
    Method main = delegate.getMethod("main", String[].class);
    main.apply(null, Arrays.asList(argv).subList(1, argv.length).toArray(argv));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One other case developing IDEs like eclipse/netbeans etc., to determine which methods in an abstract class need to be implemented by a child class, and automatically write the missing method calls for you (one example).

Answer (score 2):

Injection frameworks like [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Motivation?tm=6) or Spring use reflection to help you build instances of objects at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is also useful in cases where configuration is required to string things together.  For example, in an application I wrote I have a @Report("debits") annotation that is simply added to methods that generate reports.  Then, in the XML configuration a user can simply add:

```
<requiredReports="debits,blah,another"/>
```

This minimizes boiler plate code from mapping the XML code to the actual method, since reflection can discover the report methods and make it available directly.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to create a solution for the below statement.

"1) A diff service that:
   • can calculate the differences between two objects and return the resulting 
     "diff"
   • can apply a previously created "diff" against an original object, so that 
     the returned object matches the modified object that was used to calculate 
     the diff. "

This would have been very difficult without using reflection. Using reflection I could list all the unknown object's Class elements, properties and methods. I could use these to get the values contained in the object. I could compare the original and modified objects values, create "diff" object reflecting changes between the two objects.

Using Java reflection I could then read the instructions in the "diff" object and apply these to the original object. Java reflection gave me the tools needed to change the values on the unknown properties of the original object. I could invoke setter methods and instantiate types where needed if the original property was null to set the modified value on the original object.

The "diff" app works on any two objects of the same type, but they could be any type, both objects just have to be of the same type.

Reflection is very powerful and allow us to create true generic polymorphic methods, functions, libraries and system, where the passed object type does not need to be known at compile time. This applies when using Java Reflection and Generics together, a very powerful combination.

To end of, I have also used Java Reflection to create a generic sort function, that could sort any list of any Class Type, using any property of the Class as the sort key.As long as the calling method passed the list and the property name to use, the method would return a sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some cases to use reflection in

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        displayProperties(Stage.class);
    }

    public static void displayProperties(Class class) {
        boolean hasParam = false;
        boolean hasReturn = false;
        ArrayList<Method> propMethods = new ArrayList<>();
        Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
        for (Method m: methods) {

            Parameter[] paraType = m.getParameters();
            if(m.getParameterCount()<2) {
                if ((m.getReturnType() == void.class && paraType.length == 1) || (m.getReturnType() != void.class && paraType.length == 0)) {
                    //Get the properties alone
                    propMethods.add(m);
                }
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < propMethods.size(); i++) {

            if (propMethods.get(i).getName().startsWith("get") || propMethods.get(i).getName().startsWith("set")) {

                System.out.println(readWrite(propMethods.get(i), propMethods) + " " + propMethods.get(i).getName().substring(3)+"( "+propMethods.get(i).getReturnType().getTypeName()+" )");
            } else
                System.out.println(readWrite(propMethods.get(i), propMethods) + " " + propMethods.get(i).getName() + "( "+propMethods.get(i).getReturnType().getTypeName()+" )");
        }

    }

    public static String readWrite(Method method, ArrayList<Method> propMeths) {

        ArrayList<Method> temp;
        temp = propMeths;

        boolean readIn = false;
        boolean writeIn = false;
        String onlyName = method.getName().substring(3);

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            //use the substring--

            if (temp.get(i).getName().startsWith("get") && temp.get(i).getName().endsWith(onlyName)) {
                readIn = true;
            }
            if (temp.get(i).getName().startsWith("set") && temp.get(i).getName().endsWith(onlyName)) {

                writeIn = true;
            }
        }

        if (readIn == true && writeIn == true)
            return "rw ";
        else if (readIn == true && writeIn == false)
            return "r ";
        else
            return "w ";
    }
}
```

Another case with the String class

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        displayProperties(String.class);
    }

    public static void displayProperties(Class class){
        clazz.getDeclaredFields();

        Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();

        for(int ii = 0; ii<methods.length; ii++){
            System.out.println("Method Name: "+methods[ii].getName());
            System.out.println("Method Type: "+methods[ii].getReturnType());
            System.out.println("Method Pa: "+methods[ii].getParameterCount());
            System.out.println("Method Type: "+methods[ii].getReturnType());

        }
    }
```

Loading from XML with reflection

```
public static Object loadFromXml(String filePath) throws Exception {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        File newFile = new File(filePath);
        Document doc = builder.parse(newFile);
        Node root = doc.getFirstChild();

        return loadObjectElement(root);


    }
    /**
     * This method loads from an xml file and returns all the contents of the file as an object
     * @param root The node passed in to the method from which the "tree" gets a new level
     * @return all the contents of the xml file as an object
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static Object loadObjectElement(Node root) throws Exception {
        //loads the root
        String studentClass = root.getAttributes().getNamedItem("class").getTextContent();
        Object newStudentObject = Class.forName(studentClass).newInstance();
        //gets the children nodes (may have text elements like \n)
        NodeList studentFieldList = root.getChildNodes();

        //iterates through the children nodes
        for (int i = 0; i < studentFieldList.getLength(); i++) {
            //checks to make sure the child node is not a text node
            if (studentFieldList.item(i).getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                //checks if the current node does not have children
                if (studentFieldList.item(i).getChildNodes().getLength() == 0) {
                    //receives data of the current node
                    String nameField = studentFieldList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getTextContent();
                    String valueField = studentFieldList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getTextContent();
                    Field declaredFieldInClass = newStudentObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(nameField);

                    //makes the field accessible
                    declaredFieldInClass.setAccessible(true);
                    //checks the field type
                    switch (declaredFieldInClass.getType().getSimpleName().toLowerCase()) {
                        case "integer":
                        case "int":
                            declaredFieldInClass.set(newStudentObject, Integer.valueOf(valueField));
                            break;
                        case "float":
                            declaredFieldInClass.set(newStudentObject, Float.valueOf(valueField));
                            break;
                        case "boolean":
                            declaredFieldInClass.set(newStudentObject, Boolean.valueOf(valueField));
                            break;
                        default:
                            declaredFieldInClass.set(newStudentObject, valueField);
                    }
                    declaredFieldInClass.setAccessible(false);
                } else {
                    //there are children in the current node
                    NodeList modulesObjectList = studentFieldList.item(i).getChildNodes();
                    String nameField = studentFieldList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getTextContent();
                    Field declaredFieldInClass = newStudentObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(nameField);
                    List<Object> modules = new ArrayList<>();
                    //adds the modules into the array
                    for (int j = 0; j < modulesObjectList.getLength(); j++) {
                        if (modulesObjectList.item(j).getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                            //recursively calls the the loadObjectElement method for any sub lists
                            modules.add(loadObjectElement(modulesObjectList.item(j)));
                        }
                    }
                    //sets the modules of the specific student that the method is working with
                    declaredFieldInClass.set(newStudentObject, modules);
                }
            }
        }
        return newStudentObject;
    }
```