# Java - Invoking class methods

Tags: java

I'm following a java tutorial, i find this piece of code:

```
//load the AppTest at runtime
Class cls = Class.forName("com.mkyong.reflection.AppTest");
Object obj = cls.newInstance();

//call the printIt method
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("printIt", noparams);
method.invoke(obj, null);
```

My question is: if i don't know the class type, is not much easier (and faster) try to cast the object instead of invoking methods in that way?
Why (and when) i should use this way?

Comment: Here you have no object to cast. You create it.

Comment: why don't cast 'obj' to 'AppTest'?

Comment: If u know all about the class then why not simply create the object using new instead of reflection

Comment: @JunedAhsan I think that's exactly why he is asking this, to determine if that is exactly equivalent - is it?

Comment: Exactly, this is my question. Why create an object using 'Class.forName'?? I can't find a real example to understand

Comment: "if i don't know the class type, is not much easier (and faster) try to cast the object" - the question includes the answer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222621/java-what-scenarios-call-for-the-use-of-reflection

Comment: @bebeto123 There are plenty of real world examples available. Just try to understand any framework such as hibernate/spring etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this question
[What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

It says:

"For example, say you have an object of an unknown type in Java, **and you would like

to call a 'doSomething' method on it if one exists**. Java's static typing system
isn't really designed to support this unless the object conforms to a known
interface, but using reflection, your code can look at the object and find out if
it has a method called 'doSomething' and then call it if you want to."

You can find a good tutotial here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html

Answer (score 0):

One reason of doing it this way, not sure if in your case:

```
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("printIt", noparams);
method.invoke(obj, null);
```

will allow u to call `printIt` even if it is `private`.

But if you cast to your class object then u will not be able to call private methods.

Answer (score 0):

> If i don't know the class type, is not much easier (and faster) try to cast the object instead of invoking methods in that way?
>
> Why (and when) i should use this way?

I assume you mean "If I know" not "If I don't know" above.

If you have `com.mkyong.reflection.AppTest` at compile-time, then you wouldn't need to use reflection to use it at all. Just use it:

```
// In your imports section (although you don't *have* to do this,
// it's normal practice to avoid typing com.mkyong.reflection.AppTest
// everywhere you use it)
import com.mkyong.reflection.AppTest;

// ...and then later in a method...

//load the AppTest at runtime
AppTest obj = new AppTest();

//call the printIt method
obj.printIt();
```

If you *don't* know the class at compile-time, you can't cast the result of `newInstance` to it, because...you don't have it at compile time.

A common middle ground is *interfaces*. If `com.mkyong.reflection.AppTest` implements an interface (say, `TheInterface`), then you could do this:

```
//load the AppTest at runtime
Class cls = Class.forName("com.mkyong.reflection.AppTest");
TheInterface obj = (TheInterface)cls.newInstance();

//call the printIt method
obj.printIt();
```

At compile-time, all you need is the interface, not the implementing class. You can load the implementing class at runtime. This is a fairly common pattern for plugins (like, say, JDBC implementations).